# How should I approach statistical model development from rubric-based data?

Tags: regression, predictive-models, multivariate-analysis, model-selection

**Background**:

I am currently working in a role where I work in Assessment and Selection of right-fit applicants for teaching roles at a partner organisation. We presently use a rubric with a few competencies (or, variables) that we have selected based on qualitative research, piloting, and validation using post-selection data from training+performance data. Some of the competencies themselves have sub-parts or facets. These competencies make up our Selection "Model" or framework.

Each competency is scored on a scale of 1-5 (Each level is defined based on presence/absence of certain knowledge, skills, actions, or mindsets), and is used to assess verbal responses in an interview (final stage).

Based on the scores given according to the rubric, we currently have a simplified "model" recommendation based on the raw scores on each competency (e.g., if all scores are at least at a 3, the "model" will recommend accept). Overall, all the competencies come together to predict a certain categorical outcome (Accept/tentative/Reject). The Selector has the freedom to agree/disagree to the model recommendation based on historical training data trends for certain competencies.

**My question(s):**

My training has been in very basic quantitative and intermediate qualitative data analyses and I have never come across methods where qualitative responses (e.g., interviews) are analysed using (what I assume) quantitative methods like a rubric.

1. **Where can I read more about rubric-based research with multiple variables?** Would be helpful if it similar to my context where qualitative responses are scored on an ordinal scale?
2. **How should I go about statistical model development with the competencies so I can generate a model recommendation (accept, reject, waitlist/tentative, as shared before)?** Is it even possible? Is regression the way to go? How would I ensure that each competency (with its facets) is weighted accurately?
3. **What is the Monitoring and Evaluation approach** to keep ensuring the Model's predictiveness?

Happy to edit this or add any other information needed for clarity. All help appreciated!

---

tl;dr: I am new to rubric-based models that combine qualitative+quantitative data and need help with statistical approaches to the same.

Comment: *Rubric-based* approaches are formulas rooted in some *a priori* theory. The place to start is your organization's history wrt how their rubric came about. Otherwise, the fields of I/O psychology, organizational behavior and human resource management are the places to look for methods and papers on this topic.

Comment: @MikeHunter, Thanks for responding! So the current variables come from a larger competency framework we use, for training and development. However, now we are moving towards selecting a few predictive variables to develop a more statistically-based model for selection as well, if that makes sense. Would you have any keywords I could use to start looking for rubric-related statistics research?

Comment: Sure...I went to JSTOR.org and typed in *competency framework*  *training and development*.